# Raising to the power of individual matrix elements in piecewise functions

Tags: matlab, piecewise

I am trying to define a piecewise function in MATLAB.

```
    n = -10:10
    k(n>0) = ((1/6)^(n(n > 0))/n(n>0));
    k(n==0) = log(32);
    k(n<0) = ((1/4)^(-n(n<0)))/n(n<0);
```

MATLAB complains that I should be using an element-wise power (.^), but that's not what I want (I know because I've tried it and it gives me the wrong result). I want it to raise the fraction to each individual element of n, that fits the requirement (n<0 or n>0). Any way around this problem?

Comment: Maybe if you write your desired function in non-MATLAB notation, it will be more clear what you actually want as the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places where you need to use the `.` operator: you perform a division too:

```
n = -10:10
k(n>0) =  (1/6) .^  n(n>0)   ./ n(n>0);
k(n==0) = log(32);
k(n<0) =  (1/4) .^ -n(n<0)   ./ n(n<0);
```